# How to conditionally hide a model property

Tags: c#, .net-core, model

I have a domain model to represent a "Resource".  This is used by rest API endpoints for CRUD operations.

```
   public class ResourceDto
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ResourceTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ResourceStatusName { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ResourceModel(ResourceDto resource)
    {
        return new ResourceModel()
        {
            FirstName = resource.FirstName,
            LastName = resource.LastName,
            ResourceType = new ResourceTypeModel()
            {
                Name = resource.ResourceTypeName
            },

            ResourceStatus = new ResourceStatusModel()
            {
                StatusName = resource.ResourceStatusName
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I want to hide the `ResourceId` property in the case of the Create endpoint because it is a auto generated value in the database.  In this example I don't want them sending a value for ResourceId.
[image]

But they will need to get the Id coming back from a Read so they can supply it for an Update or Delete.

I've looked at the json method `ShouldSerialize` but that will only hide it coming out from the Domain to the end point.

I've tried data annotations.  `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` didn't seem to do anything and  `[JsonIgnore]` hides it completely.

The only thing I can think of is to create two Resource models, one with the id and one without.  If I'm thinking about this the wrong way, I welcome some redirection as well.  Thanks.

Comment: *"The only thing I can think of is to create two Resource models, one with the id and one without."* - That's how I'd do it.  The input to a "create" operation is subtly different than the output of a "get" operation, so the models should reflect that.

Comment: @David is it bad that it thought the obvious answer seemed too simple?  I was afraid there was some technique that I wasn't aware of and I would look stupid creating two models.  <ugh>

Comment: There *might* be a declarative solution for any given tool being used, but the more tools we throw into the mix the more muddied those waters get.  (JSON serialization, Swagger documentation, etc.)  A separate model is always clear.  Failing that, if anyone on the team were to insist on using the same model, it could be decorated with intellisense comments indicating something like "this field is ignored on Create operations".